# configure my web developed in local to web host

Tags: laravel-4, web-hosting

I've done some small demo of a web site and I hope to send it to a web host, but the preblem is after updating my folders and type the address, it just cannot find my web page. On local I use linux + XAMPP + Laravel so the structure is

```
/htdocs/laravel/public
               /app
               /vendor
```

and I just type

```
http://localhost/laravel/public/mywebpage
```

to access my web. But to use a web host who provides a file position like:

```
/home/sitename/public_html
```

do i need to create/modify any configuration file??

Comment: Here is a nice guide with a few different solutions, http://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host

Comment: @Hoshts I've followed but it doesn't work. error 404 ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try renaming your local `public` folder to `public_html` and reflect this change at  the `/bootstrap/paths.php` file.

There you'll find `'public' => __DIR__.'/../public'`, change `../public` to `../public_html` in this case.

I have to do something similar when I upload a laravel app to **OpenShift**, for example.

Comment: tried, doesn't work ... can you recommend some tutorial about this topic? explain the mechnism of the files and management.

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file in your public_html folder? Do you have access above /public_html level?

Comment: Here is a tutorial to upload a laravel app to HostGator shared plan, http://shincoding.com/laravel/installing-configuring-laravel-shared-hosting/

Comment: thank you, I will try this one and tell you the result.